# Excel F2 or sendkeys{F2} cell resizing

Tags: excel, vba

How to prevent Excel to change size of cell when i press F2 or with VBA do sendkeys{F2} on cell?
Why Excel change cells Height (if it < 15pt) in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple :)

Even though you have reduced the cell size, you have forgotten to decrease the font size so when you press <kbd>F2</kbd>, the cursor will show you as per the font size of that cell.

See the screenshot below. If I reduce the size to `Calibri-5`, the cursor also decreases.

[image]